# OpenCV VideoCapture memory leak

Tags: python, opencv, memory-leaks

I'm running opencv in a system with very limited resources. There're two cameras used, and I can't have them both occupying the memory. So I have to activate/deactivate them all the time. However, there seems to be a memory leak each time I do it. Here's an example showing the problem:

```
import cv2

while True:
    cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cap.set(3,1920)
    cap.set(4,1080)
    stat,img=cap.read()  #this line creates a memory leak
    cap.release()
```

I tested it in Ubuntu and the memory leak is also there.
By any chance can I fix it?

Comment: This may be a good candidate for the OpenCV mailing list

Comment: Yeah, I'm also hoping there's quick solution/workaround

Comment: Any solution to this? Did you figure out how to fix?